# Xcode 10 - iPhone X black bars

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been searching for days now and I am really going crazy.
I have re-openend an old project last edited with xcode 9 (I did not care about the iPhone X screen until now) in my freshly updated Xcode 10.

No matter what I do I can't get my app to use the whole screen for iPhone X.

At first I noticed I was not using safe area layout guide - ok, added it for a test view, still black bars.

I'm using storyboards and have set up a test storyboard with no view controller or something else, only a single view inside the safe area and yellow background. This storyboard I have set to be the main interface.
In project settings I have enabled "Requires full screen". 
In Xcode Editor everything looks good:
[image: Xcode Editor view]

However, the result in simulator (and also on a friends real iPhone X) is like this:
[image]

Is someone able to help? This does NOT happen when I create a new project, but of course I would very much like to avoid using this option as the app is almost completely developed....

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Does your project use a launch screen storyboard or are you using launch images?

Comment: omg seriously ?! changing to launch screen storyboard solved it
thanks @rmaddy ! 
Do I need to understand why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to rmaddy I changed from launch screen image to storyboard and the problem disappeared... how stupid of me to ignore that while googling.. :)

Comment: I got this same problem and have pulled my hair for some time. :)